# How can you programmatically click a button on ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify

I working on an ajax cart function for an e-commerce store and the functionality I require is that when the add to cart button is clicked, the item is added to cart then the user is directed to the checkout page.

The scenario I'd like to accomplish is as follows: Have a 'Buy It Now' button and once clicked, change to 'Processing'. When in the 'Processing' state, an ID is added and I need the resulting button to be clicked.

The original ajax cart code is here: https://github.com/carolineschnapp/ajaxify-cart/blob/master/ajaxify-cart.liquid

I've attempted to add `$('checkout').trigger('click');` as seen in the code below, although it's not working as I've intended.

```
success: function(itemData) {
            // Re-enable add to cart button.
            $addToCartBtn.addClass('inverted');
            _setText($addToCartBtn, _config.addedToCartBtnLabel);

            window.setTimeout(function(){
              $addToCartBtn.prop('disabled', false).removeClass('disabled').removeClass('inverted');
              _setText($addToCartBtn,_config.addedToCartBtnLabel);

            }, _config.howLongTillBtnReturnsToNormal);
            $addToCartBtn.attr('id', 'checkout');
            $('checkout').trigger('click');
```

Comment: guessing `$('checkout')` is supposed to be `$('#checkout')`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using jquery,

$('#buttonid').trigger('click');

Comment: Hey, I've posted a snippet of my code so far with that code although I'm not sure I've added it in the right place.

Comment: You can also use document.getElementById('').click()

Comment: As per Dementic's answer, in JQuery elements referenced by id need to be prefaced with a '#', whereas elements referenced by class need a '.'. You can also select DOM objects like input, tr, etc. JQuery selection very closely follows css selection.